# Use merge method with scope while eager loading with includes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, merge, eager-loading

This is a follow up question to watching a video at [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com) on Scopes, as well as watching a video by [Chris Oliver](https://gorails.com/episodes/named-scopes-with-activerecord-merge) on the merge method.

What I am trying to do is find only those `authors` which have at least one `book` that is available.  Then after it filters for those `authors`, I want to eager load all of the `books` for those selected `authors` because I do not want to query the database each time I pull data out about those books. I tried a number of different scopes but none of them are giving me exactly what I need:

```
#app/models/book.rb 
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  scope :available, ->{where(availability: true)}
  scope :unavailable, ->{where(availability: false)}
end

#app/models/author.rb
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy

  scope :with_available_books, ->{joins(:books).merge(Book.available)}
  scope :with_available_books_uniq, ->{uniq.joins(:books).merge(Book.available)}
  scope :with_available_books_includes, ->{joins(:books).merge(Book.available).includes(:books)}
  scope :with_available_books_uniq_includes, ->{uniq.joins(:books).merge(Book.available).includes(:books)}

  def to_s
    self.name
  end
end
```

Here is what is a snapshot of what is in my databases
I have **three** `authors`:

1. `Neil`, and he has 10 associated books total, **ALL are available**
2. `John`, and he has 10 associated books total, **ALL are unavailable**
3. `Mixture Author`, and he has 10 books total, **5 are available, 5 are unavailable**

I ran all the queries and outputted the results in HTML. Here is what I am getting:

```
# Duplicating the authors AND N + 1 problem with associated books
```

Author.with_available_books.size: 15 
  Books for author[0]: 10
  Books for author`[1]`: 10

```
# Fixed the duplication but still N + 1 problem with the associated books
```

Author.with_available_books_uniq.size: 2 
  Books for author[0]: 10
  Books for author`[1]`: 10

```
# Fixed the N + 1 problem but duplicating authors
```

Author.with_available_books_includes.size: 15

```
# Fixed the duplication and fixed the N + 1 problem
# BUT now it is filtering out the unavailable books!
# But I want all the Books for these authors!
```

Author.with_available_books_uniq_includes.size: 2
  Books for author[0]: 10
  Books for author`[1]`: 5

How do I grab ALL the books for the unduplicated authors?  I want to filter the authors by their associated object's attribute (the `available` attribute on the books), and I want to eager load those books.

Comment: `joins` does not eager load anything thus your n + 1 eager_load however will load this data in 1 query. Also since you are filtering on `books` includes will also run a single query. Here is a great [Article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html) on the different loading methods in rails

Comment: @engineersmnky I was aware that `joins` does not eager load, so that was why I added the `includes` statement.  I thought that would fix the issue, but it returns unexpected results.

Comment: try seeing what actual queries look like (you can just add `.to_sql` to the end of the query chain). I think that will help you because right now you are making 2 different joins to the same table. `joins` will create and INNER JOIN and `includes` will create an OUTER JOIN so your query will be something like `SELECT authors.* FROM authors INNER JOIN books b1 ON authors.id = b1.author_id LEFT OUTER JOIN books b2 ON authors.id = b2.author_id...` (see the issue?)

Comment: @engineersmnky Ok here is where I am at.  I am able to grab the appropriate authors just fine like so: `@authors_with_available_books = Author.with_available_books_uniq`.
OK, Now I want to eager load their books for performance.  How do I do that?  This doesn't work: `@auths_and_eager_loaded_books = @authors_with_available_books.includes(:books)`.  That only loads some of the books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks TREMENDOUSLY to [Chris Oliver](https://gorails.com) himself for responding to my email query about this situation.

First grab the authors:

```
@uniq_authors_with_available_books = Author.with_available_books_uniq
```

This properly grabs `Neil` and `Mixture Author` who both have available books:

```
2.2.1 :004 > @authors_with_available_books.size
=> 2
```

However, as can be seen below, the `N + 1` problem is still present if we want to grab any info about those two authors' books:

```
2.2.1 :005 > @authors_with_available_books[0].books.size
  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books" WHERE "books"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 1]]
=> 10 

2.2.1 :006 > @authors_with_available_books[1].books.size
  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books" WHERE "books"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 3]]
=> 10
```

So thanks to Chris's advice.  What we have to do is a separate query on books with a `subquery` using the `id`'s from the `@authors_with_available_books`:

```
2.2.1 :007 > @books_by_those_authors = Book.where(author_id: @authors_with_available_books.map(&:id)) 
  Book Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."author_id" IN (1, 3)
```

From the sql query we can see that it is grabbing only those books where the `id` is equal to `1` or `3`.  It is only grabbing those authors because the first query told us that only those authors are the ones with available books.

Now I can do this:

```
@books.size
=> 20
```

Which makes sense because `Neil` has ten total books and `Mixture Author` has ten total books, yielding a combined total of `20`.